# What is the difference between JFrame.getContentPane() and JFrame.getRootPane()?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

What is the difference between Java frame functions `getContentPane()` and `getRootPane()`?
Also what wil happen when we set a JButton as Default.

Comment: You got the answer I see. Remember, fortunately, most of the time you will not need to get those Panes. For example, in earlier version of Java (Someone knows the exact version?) you needed to add components by JFrame.getRootPane(...) now just JFrame.Add(...) is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While using top-level containers in AWT or Swing, the root pane is the base pane.

The hierarchy is as follows:

1. Glass Pane: Generally hidden, setting to visible will show up a glass cover over the root pane areas.
2. Layered Pane: Contains the Menubar and the Content Pane
3. Content Pane: Is the basic layout pane in which components are actually placed.

Calling the method `getRootPane()` will return the reference to the base pane, while calling the `getContentPane()` method will get you the reference to the Content Pane. It is visible by default.

By setting Jbutton default, What are you exactly trying to accomplish?

Comment: venomrld ,Thanx i have got my ans what i want.....bt there is again a Glass pane which i am not able to understand much can you tell me more abt Glass Pane?

Comment: A particular use of glasspane is adding or painting a particular area on the Frame which already contains components. Especially useful if you need to add components or repaint without disturbin current layout.

Answer (score 14):

from [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html):

> getContentPane() is generally implemented like this:
>
> ```
> public Container getContentPane() {
>     return getRootPane().getContentPane();
> }
> ```

It's well described in Swing tutorial ([here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)).

[image]

Comment: Thanx Michal, the information you have just given is really very help full bt i want to know what they represents???

Answer (score 1):

The Root Pane, as the name implies, is the root of the frame/window/dialog.

Its contains als other components of this top-level component.
the content pane is one of the four parts of the root pane and contains the components. the other parts of the root pane are glass pane, layered pane and a optional menu bar.

the tutorials at oracle explains this really good:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html